# External storage: can't query a file that I have read access to

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage, chromebook

I am using a "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" intent to choose a file and open it.

This works just fine when I go to read the file.

However, when the file resides on EXTERNAL storage, and I run a query to obtain the file name, my program crashes. If the file resides on INTERNAL storage, I have no issues.

I DO have (and check for) external storage access permissions.

I have the query enclosed in a try{}, but the exception is not caught. I am developing on a Chrome book, so I am unable to run the debugger on it. But I have isolated the issue to the **result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));** statement.

I know that access to files on external storage has been limited, but I would think that if I can read a file that I should also be able to query it as well.

Here is my code:

```
package com.muddco.demo3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity mAct;
    TextView rvalue, fnamevalue;
    Button btn1, btn2;
    Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        rvalue = findViewById(R.id.readResult);
        fnamevalue = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mAct = this;

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*
                 * Launch a file picker
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("*/*");

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a GPX file"), 1);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*
                 * Get and display file name
                 */
                String fname = getFileName(fileUri);
                fnamevalue.setText(fname);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission granted and now can proceed
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            // add other cases for more permissions
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        Uri uri = null;

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                // Process GPX file
                uri = data.getData();
                try {
                     inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                    rvalue.setText(readFile(inputStream));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "File not found: " + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //String fName = getFileName(uri);
                //Toast.makeText(mAct, "Filename: "+fName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fileUri = uri;
                btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Read a FileStream
     *
     */
    String readFile(InputStream is) {
        String ret = "";
        String line = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ret += line + "\n";
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if any I/O error occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "Exception!";
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /*
    * Obtain the filename from a URI
     */
public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        String result = "<empty>";
        Cursor cursor;

        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                cursor = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cursor exception: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    //
                    // THE NEXT STATEMENT CRASHES WHEN FILE RESIDES ON EXTERNAL STORAGE
                    //
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(mAct, "Bad cursor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return "Bad Cursor";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cursor exception: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return "Cursoe Exception";
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        else
            result="Non content URI";

        return result;
    }
}
```

When I press the first button, the file requestor pops up and I select my test text file. The contents of the file are listed in a textbox, then a second button is made visible. When that second button is pressed, I query the file and place the filename in a second textbox.

The entire project, along with the test.txt file I am using to test, can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O_pQBqbo4z05ghr2Rj3uzZfuUuqlxAQi?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use `DocumentFile` to get the display name for your document. Also note that `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not access what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). It does offer [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), and possibly other things (e.g., Google Drive).

Comment: Using DocumentFile may be a way of circumventing the problem, but it doesn't answer my question: Why does the query not work?

Comment: I don't know that the Storage Access Framework directly supports the `OpenableColumns` that way. Beyond that, without a stack trace, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Understood. I am waiting to hear from some friends that may be able to run it under a simulator so the stack trace can be captured. I do not know of a way to get the "logcat", or equivalent, for an app running under Chrome OS.  And, my phone doesn't have a SD slot...

Comment: For Chrome OS, https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/development-environment gets you `adb` access, for use with Android Studio or command-line `adb logcat` commands.

Comment: Please tell the value of uri.toString() where getting display name fails. Further ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT only gives files from external memory. Internal memory is not reachable for it. Please tell better what you do and when it goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare for the tip. I was able to run adb from a Linux terminal on my Chromebook. I am now looking at what is going wrong.....

Comment: OK, I actually WAS capturing the exception, but then triggered another exception when I tried to close the cursor with a null pointer. So.... we are now trying to figure out why the ContentResolver.query() is returning null. And , when I refer to "Internal" storage, I am referring to storage that is on my device's internal "drive", as opposed to a SD card or USB drive. Files placed in my Chromebook's "Downloads" folder work just fine with my program. Files on a SD card or USB drive produce the null pointer from the ContentResolver.query()

Comment: Here is a URI, that works: ```content://org.chromium.arc.file_system.fileprovider/download/test2.txt``` 
A uri that doesnt work: ```content://org.chromium.arc.volumeprovider/removable/SDCard/Downloads/test%202.txt```

Comment: I finally found my OTG cable, so I tried my demo app on my Pixel 3 (Android 10) with a USB thumb drive. It worked just fine, no null cursor. So, either this issue is specific to Chrome OS, or perhaps the release of Android  it is running (Android 9). I will be reporting this to Google, unless someone can point to me what I am doing incorrectrly.